# mapply with two lists and a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function for use within mapply that involves two lists and a data frame.  I want to pick out several subsets of data indexed by the two lists (for row and column).  Here's an example of what I want to do in a loop, and my attempt at the function:

```
#simulated data and column, row indexes
set.seed(100)
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:100,nrow=10,ncol=10))
y <- lapply(vector("list", 5),function(x){sample(1:10,5)}) 
x <- as.list(c(1,3,5,7,9),length=5)

# version in loop
whatiwant <- list(length=5)
for (i in 1:5){
   whatiwant[[i]] <- d[y[[i]],x[[i]]]
}

fun <- function(x,y,d){d[y,x]}

whatiwant2 <- mapply(fun,y,x,MoreArgs=d)
```

From the error given, I suspect that mapply is trying to apply this function to each column of d; how do I avoid this?  If I were only indexing one dimension (.e.g the row) and a single column, the equivalent using lapply would be:

```
onedim <- lapply(y,function(d,y){d[y]},d=d[,1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MoreArgs` parameter expects a list containing the aditional parameters. Since a data.frame is a list, `mapply` thinks that the data.frame columns are the additional parameters and complains that the function doesn't use these. You need to wrap your data.frame in `list`. You also should set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to get a list returned.

```
whatiwant2 <- mapply(fun, y = y, x = x, MoreArgs=list(d), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1]  7 10  4  6  3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 21 29 26 27 30
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 48 47 45 42 50
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 62 70 69 67 66
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 86 90 89 88 81
```

Comment: Good tip. I get a different result though. e.g. `[[5]] [1] 83 87 88 89 85` I used `fun <- function(x,y,d){d[y,x]}` and `mapply(fun, y = y, x = x, MoreArgs=list(d), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: That is not surprising. You example input is not reproducible because you didn't set a random seed.

Comment: truth. I also found another way to get the result without the `MoreArgs` confusion. There's no need to make `d` an argument. `fun <- function(x,y){d[y,x]}` and `mapply(fun, x, y, SIMPLIFY=F)` What do you think, @Roland?

Comment: @plafort Making it an argument is better practice (I was actually positively impressed that they did so). Scoping is safer that way.

Comment: I added set.seed() to the original question to improve reproducibility for future reference.  thanks.